# How can I check if the cart has shippable products?

Tags: 8, ubercart

How can I check if the cart has any shippable product in Ubercart 3 for Drupal 8? Previous version had `uc_cart_is_shippable()` method which Drupal 8 module does not seem to have by default.

Is there a separate/additional module to get this function working? Or how else can I check if the cart has a shippable product?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function is now a part of the [`CartInterface`](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/ubercart/blob/8.x-4.x/uc_cart/src/CartInterface.php#L68) and implemented in the [`Cart::isShippable()`](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/ubercart/blob/8.x-4.x/uc_cart/src/Cart.php#L193) method. You can use the [`CartManager`](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/ubercart/blob/8.x-4.x/uc_cart/src/CartManager.php) service to retrieve the `Cart` object and call the method:

```
\Drupal::service('uc_cart.manager')->get()->isShippable()
```

Comment: Thanks @Shawn Conn

Comment: do we have the equivalent function for uc_cart_product_is_shippable() as well?